# Only perturb a small portion of tensor image in Tensorflow Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working through the cleverhans python library.

I have an image:

```
faces1.shape

> (1, 160, 160, 3)
```

I want to perturb the pixels in this image using this FGSM method:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Load model
        model = InceptionResnetV1Model()
        # Convert to classifier
        model.convert_to_classifier()

        # Load pairs of faces and their labels in one-hot encoding
        faces1, faces2, labels = set_loader.load_testset(1)

        # Create victims' embeddings using Facenet itself
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        phase_train_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")
        feed_dict = {model.face_input: faces2,
                     phase_train_placeholder: False}
        victims_embeddings = sess.run(
            model.embedding_output, feed_dict=feed_dict)

        # Define FGSM for the model
        steps = 1
        eps = 0.01
        alpha = eps / steps
        fgsm = FastGradientMethod(model)
        fgsm_params = {'eps': alpha,
                       'clip_min': 0.,
                       'clip_max': 1.}
        adv_x = fgsm.generate(x = model.face_input, **fgsm_params)

        # Run FGSM
        adv = faces1
        for i in range(steps):
            print("FGSM step " + str(i + 1))
            feed_dict = {model.face_input: adv,
                         model.victim_embedding_input: victims_embeddings,
                         phase_train_placeholder: False}
            adv = sess.run(adv_x, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        plt.imshow((np.squeeze(adv) * 255).round().astype(np.uint8))
        plt.show()
```

And this returns an image that is perturbed throughout and can fool the initial detection model. **However, I want to only perturb a small portion of the image and get the same effect**

Here is the model they use to perform the perturbation:

```
def fgm(x, preds, y=None, eps=0.3, ord=np.inf,
        clip_min=None, clip_max=None,
        targeted=False):
    """
    TensorFlow implementation of the Fast Gradient Method.
    :param x: the input placeholder
    :param preds: the model's output tensor (the attack expects the
                  probabilities, i.e., the output of the softmax)
    :param y: (optional) A placeholder for the model labels. If targeted
              is true, then provide the target label. Otherwise, only provide
              this parameter if you'd like to use true labels when crafting
              adversarial samples. Otherwise, model predictions are used as
              labels to avoid the "label leaking" effect (explained in this
              paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01236). Default is None.
              Labels should be one-hot-encoded.
    :param eps: the epsilon (input variation parameter)
    :param ord: (optional) Order of the norm (mimics NumPy).
                Possible values: np.inf, 1 or 2.
    :param clip_min: Minimum float value for adversarial example components
    :param clip_max: Maximum float value for adversarial example components
    :param targeted: Is the attack targeted or untargeted? Untargeted, the
                     default, will try to make the label incorrect. Targeted
                     will instead try to move in the direction of being more
                     like y.
    :return: a tensor for the adversarial example
    """

    if y is None:
        # Using model predictions as ground truth to avoid label leaking
        preds_max = tf.reduce_max(preds, 1, keep_dims=True)
        y = tf.to_float(tf.equal(preds, preds_max))
        y = tf.stop_gradient(y)
    y = y / tf.reduce_sum(y, 1, keep_dims=True)

    # Compute loss
    loss = utils_tf.model_loss(y, preds, mean=False)
    if targeted:
        loss = -loss

    # Define gradient of loss wrt input
    grad, = tf.gradients(loss, x)

    if ord == np.inf:
        # Take sign of gradient
        normalized_grad = tf.sign(grad)
        # The following line should not change the numerical results.
        # It applies only because `normalized_grad` is the output of
        # a `sign` op, which has zero derivative anyway.
        # It should not be applied for the other norms, where the
        # perturbation has a non-zero derivative.
        normalized_grad = tf.stop_gradient(normalized_grad)
    elif ord == 1:
        red_ind = list(xrange(1, len(x.get_shape())))
        normalized_grad = grad / tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(grad),
                                               reduction_indices=red_ind,
                                               keep_dims=True)
    elif ord == 2:
        red_ind = list(xrange(1, len(x.get_shape())))
        square = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grad),
                               reduction_indices=red_ind,
                               keep_dims=True)
        normalized_grad = grad / tf.sqrt(square)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("Only L-inf, L1 and L2 norms are "
                                  "currently implemented.")

    # Multiply by constant epsilon
    scaled_grad = eps * normalized_grad

    # Add perturbation to original example to obtain adversarial example
    adv_x = x + scaled_grad

    # If clipping is needed, reset all values outside of [clip_min, clip_max]
    if (clip_min is not None) and (clip_max is not None):
        adv_x = tf.clip_by_value(adv_x, clip_min, clip_max)

    return adv_x
```

As you can see, the key line here is `adv_x = x + scaled_grad` where x is the input image and it is getting perturbed by the `scaled_grad`.

```
print(scaled_grad)

> Tensor("mul_5:0", shape=(?, 160, 160, 3), dtype=float32)
```

and

```
print(x)

> Tensor("input:0", shape=(?, 160, 160, 3), dtype=float32)
```

So what I want to be able to do is extract a portion of `x` when the gradient is being taken so the gradient is of the same shape as the portion of `x`, then I want to perturb only that portion of `x` and then I want to reattach the remainder of `x` back on to the perturbed portion so that it outputs as the same image as before only the portion defined is perturbed and the rest is not.

Answer (score 1):

Most attacks in CleverHans do not allow the user to specify which features of the input should be modified. It is however possible to adapt some existing attacks to have this behavior.

For instance, in the JSMA attack, you can mask some of the features when computing the saliency maps to have the attack only consider a specific subset of features when constructing the perturbation of the input (a specific subset of pixels in your case). You would have to modify the following snippet of code in the `jsma_symbolic` function found in `cleverhans/attacks_tf.py`:

```
# Create a mask to only keep features that match conditions
if increase:
  scores_mask = ((target_sum > 0) & (other_sum < 0))
else:
  scores_mask = ((target_sum < 0) & (other_sum > 0))
```

You can also find an example of this type of behavior in the adversarial patch work by Brown et al. where they constrained the perturbation added to an image to create an adversarial example to be a small patch in the image: https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/tree/master/examples/adversarial_patch

Comment: Awesome! This is super helpful. I was actually able to obtain the results by modifying the `fgm` function to mask the gradient using black/white .png's I generated beforehand and passing these in as ROI's. Do you think JSMA would be more effective for this type of attack? Also, does it make sense to implement FGSM in this way?

Comment: What do you mean by ROI?

Comment: Region of Interest

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I would say that it depends which norm you are trying to minimize when finding the perturbation. The JSMA is designed to minimize the number of features perturbed while the FGSM is designed to minimize the maximum change made to any features. So my guess would be that if your ROI is large, the FGSM will work well, and instead if your ROI is small, the JSMA will work well.